# Incrementing a counter in switch that determines when something is full

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a class that contains variables about how many passengers a bus can take onboard. It can take 57 seat-passenger, 2 wheelchairs, 2 strollers and 27 standing people.

In the main class I have a switch statement where the user chooses between these 4 types of passengers (I have a method called Menu where they chooses from), depending on which type it chooses, it will fall into one of the 4 cases in the switch.

In each switch I have a counter which will be incremented by 1 for each time the user chooses that case. However, when this counter is equal to the amount of seats on the bus, it should write out that it is full.

My problem: The counter simply keeps incrementing by every time I choose the cases, so it doesn't stop incrementing even when it is greater than the available seats.

```
    Menu ();
    boolean choice = true;
    do {
    int passengerType = input.nextInt();
    switch (passengerType) {
        case 1:
            int occupiedSeat=0;
            if (bus1.getSeats() > occupiedSeat) {
                occupiedSeat ++;
                bus1.setSeats(occupiedSeat);
                System.out.println("One seatpassenger onboard. ");
                } else {
                System.out.println("No available seats left.");
                } Menu ();
            break; 

           //Same with the other three cases

             } 
         } while(choice);
```

I have tried with for loops as well, but it did not work either. Does any one know what I have done wrong?

Comment: It would be better to define an enum for the passenger type.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are creating `int occupiedSeat=0;` in the `switch case` statement, it will cause `occupiedSeat` always less than `bus1.getSeats()`.

You need declare `occupiedSeat` out the `do while` loop:

```
int occupiedSeat=0;

do {

} while ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `int occupiedSeat=0;` **before** the loop and not **in** the loop otherwise it reinitializes the value to `0` at each iteration :

```
int occupiedSeat=0;
do {
int passengerType = input.nextInt();
     switch (passengerType) {
        ...
     }

} while(choice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `int occupiedSeat=0;` outside the `switch` because each time when you run it it's get value `occupiedSeat=0`

```
 Menu ();
    int occupiedSeat=0;
    boolean choice = true;
    do {
    int passengerType = input.nextInt();
    switch (passengerType) {
        case 1:
            if (bus1.getSeats() > occupiedSeat) {
                occupiedSeat ++;
                bus1.setSeats(occupiedSeat);
                System.out.println("One seatpassenger onboard. ");
                } else {
                System.out.println("No available seats left.");
                } Menu ();
            break; 

           //Same with the other three cases

             } 
         } while(choice);
```